# Is Super User only for *personal* computers?

Tags: discussion

What about other computing questions, about things such as PDAs?
I guess this is kind of related to [Are iPhone, iPod, iPod touch questions computer related (SuperUser)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/are-iphone-ipod-ipod-touch-questions-computer-related-superuser)

Comment: @Nathaniel Listen to the TheTXI. He's actually a mod.

Comment: Thus the diamond character, right?

Comment: Yes, the diamond indicates a moderator.

Comment: Jeff is also a mod. Here's a recent close: http://superuser.com/questions/45364/touch-arcade-iphone

Answer (score 9):

SuperUser is for generally all consumer computing questions. This can involve computer hardware such as everything in the actual computer casing, to monitors, printers, routers, etc. etc. etc.

Smartphones such as the iPhone and blackberry are also legitimate questions. iPod Touch is generally accepted since it is using the same OS as the iPhone. Other iPod and mp3 player questions generally must have some form of computer interaction involved for it to be legitimate.

Comment: +1, I was going to post something similar, but I saw this post when I was in a drive-thru lane. It seemed imprudent to type something like this on a phone while behind the wheel, waiting for steaming hot heart attacky goodness. :)

Answer (score 6):

Unless your peripheral device hooks up to the computer, then it will most likely be closed as not a computer question.

So even if the iPhone or PDA has computing parts and guts, it's not considered appropriate/related for SU unless you have it interacting with the computer.

Comment: Got it. Best answer for now.

Comment: This is not correct. iPhone and iPod Touch questions along with other smartphone questions are generally accepted.

Comment: @Nathaniel That's why you should wait for more than a few minutes when picking an answer. Wait. Not everyone is up at the same time. You could be getting horrible answers in the mean time. Case in point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23239/where-is-your-pony-god-now/23240#23240

Comment: Well, you can change the answer, but maybe I should wait for a while longer before marking an answer. Thanks for the guidance. What's with the rewritten link, though? Pony god?

Comment: Leaving the answer as is. It's good to collect any downvotes if it's wrong. For the pony: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479